# Laravel 5.2 routes not working properly

Tags: php, laravel, routes

i'm new to Laravel and I'm having some issues with the routes class

Here is my **routes.php**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::auth();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

Route::resource('/dashboard', 'DashboardController');
Route::resource('/dashboard/users', 'DashboardUsersController');
Route::resource('/dashboard/posts', 'DashboardPostsController');
```

All of the above routes are working except

```
app.dev/dashboard/users/index
app.dev/dashboard/posts/index
```

every route that i create like

```
Route::get('dashboard/users/import', function (){
    return 'Importing a user';
});
```

or

```
Route::get('dashboard/users', 'DashboardUsersController@getUsers');
```

I already tried some suggestions that I've found here, like cleaning the cache, view and route but none worked, my project folder's permission is 777

Here's my **DashboardUsersController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class DashboardUsersController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('admin.users.index');
    }


    public function getUsers()
    {
        return view('admin.users.index');
    }


    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('admin.users.index');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        return view('admin.users.index');
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

**Edit php artisan route:list**

```
+--------+-----------+------------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI                          | Name                    | Action                                                          | Middleware |
+--------+-----------+------------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | /                            |                         | Closure                                                         | web        |
|        | POST      | dashboard                    | dashboard.store         | App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController@store                  | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | dashboard                    | dashboard.index         | App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController@index                  | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | dashboard/create             | dashboard.create        | App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController@create                 | web        |
|        | POST      | dashboard/posts              | dashboard.posts.store   | App\Http\Controllers\DashboardPostsController@store             | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | dashboard/posts              | dashboard.posts.index   | App\Http\Controllers\DashboardPostsController@index             | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | dashboard/posts/create       | dashboard.posts.create  | App\Http\Controllers\DashboardPostsController@create            | web        |
|        | PUT|PATCH | dashboard/posts/{posts}      | dashboard.posts.update  | App\Http\Controllers\DashboardPostsController@update            | web        |
|        | DELETE    | dashboard/posts/{posts}      | dashboard.posts.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\DashboardPostsController@destroy           | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | dashboard/posts/{posts}      | dashboard.posts.show    | App\Http\Controllers\DashboardPostsController@show              | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | dashboard/posts/{posts}/edit | dashboard.posts.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\DashboardPostsController@edit              | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | dashboard/users              | dashboard.users.index   | App\Http\Controllers\DashboardUsersController@getUsers          | web        |
|        | POST      | dashboard/users              | dashboard.users.store   | App\Http\Controllers\DashboardUsersController@store             | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | dashboard/users/create       | dashboard.users.create  | App\Http\Controllers\DashboardUsersController@create            | web        |
|        | DELETE    | dashboard/users/{users}      | dashboard.users.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\DashboardUsersController@destroy           | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | dashboard/users/{users}      | dashboard.users.show    | App\Http\Controllers\DashboardUsersController@show              | web        |
|        | PUT|PATCH | dashboard/users/{users}      | dashboard.users.update  | App\Http\Controllers\DashboardUsersController@update            | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | dashboard/users/{users}/edit | dashboard.users.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\DashboardUsersController@edit              | web        |
|        | PUT|PATCH | dashboard/{dashboard}        | dashboard.update        | App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController@update                 | web        |
|        | DELETE    | dashboard/{dashboard}        | dashboard.destroy       | App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController@destroy                | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | dashboard/{dashboard}        | dashboard.show          | App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController@show                   | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | dashboard/{dashboard}/edit   | dashboard.edit          | App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController@edit                   | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | home                         |                         | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index                       | web,auth   |
|        | GET|HEAD  | login                        |                         | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm          | web,guest  |
|        | POST      | login                        |                         | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@login                  | web,guest  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | logout                       |                         | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@logout                 | web        |
|        | POST      | password/email               |                         | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail | web,guest  |
|        | POST      | password/reset               |                         | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@reset              | web,guest  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | password/reset/{token?}      |                         | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@showResetForm      | web,guest  |
|        | POST      | register                     |                         | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@register               | web,guest  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | register                     |                         | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm   | web,guest  |
+--------+-----------+------------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

Like I said all above routes are working, except the

```
/dashboard/users
/dashboard/posts
```

that should be routing to the `index` method of the DashboardUsersController and DashboardPostsController, and every custom route that i create.

When i removed the `Route::resource` the `Route::get('dashboard/users', 'DashboardUsersController@index');` worked, so could be a bug? or something that I forgot to setup?

**Edit 2**

When I tried the

```
Route::get('dashboard/users', 'DashboardUsersController@getUsers');
```

I removed the

```
Route::resource('/dashboard/users', 'DashboardUsersController');
```

to make sure it didn't conflict, and still not worked

Comment: Use `php artisan route:list` to examine the routes you are defining

Comment: What happens if you change the order so "Route::resource('/dashboard', 'DashboardController');" is at the bottom?

Comment: I edited my answer where I explain what happens when you use Route::resource so that my answer is complete. I hope that helps.

Comment: Yeah helped, but i still don't understand why just the `index` methods of the `DashboardUsersController` and `DashboardPostsController`, didn't work, but the `create`, `edit` etc were working

Comment: @CesarHenriqueDamascena I explained that in my answer. And Michal has basically incorporated what I've said into his answer. The rest of his answer makes no sense. What a waste of time trying to help you if all you do is accept the wrong answer... as explained... you made an additional get route that conflicted with a get route created by the resource type route. The others don't conflict simply because you didn't make any conflicting routes with them. What Michal basically suggests - that you stop using `resource` in favour of the "normal methods"  -whatever that means, is an anti-solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity use `Route::get` for normal methods in controller and `Route::post` for methods that are receiving `$_POST` data from form.

Second parameter of `Route::get` / `Route::post` method is ControllerName@MethodName. Try to change it accordingly.

Try not to forget namespace.

**Edit:**
When using `Route::resource` you are actually generating all possible RESTful routes for your controller. You can not make that more than once. That is the reason why changing `Route::resource` to `Route::get` did work.

You can find more information here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers

Comment: Yeah, when I removed all of the **Route::resource** worked, why when I create more than 1, the routes stop to working properly, it's a bug?

Comment: To be honest I learned something new too. :) From here https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers I understood that when using Route::resource u are actually adding all possible RESTfull routes to your controller. You can not make that more than once.

Comment: Which is why this is not exactly an answer, whether helpful or not. The problem is that he's making a conflicting route as I've highlighted in my answer

Comment: @Jonathan, sorry that was an example, When I tried the  `Route::get('/dashboard/users', 'DashboardUsersController@getUsers')` ,       I commented the `Route::resource('/dashboard/users','DashboardUsersController')` to test, and still not worked

Comment: It's not cool to incorporate what I've said in my answer in your own... if your problem was resolved by removing either route then my answer is correct. You conflicted the route when using the resource and I've explained that for you in no clearer way possible...

Answer (score 0):

You're not really very clear on what is working and what isn't working. You're also adding more code for illustrative purposes and we're having to fill in the gaps in the assumptions as to what you're doing.

When you define a resource e.g. `Route::resource('/users', 'UserController');` you get the following routes:

```
|        | GET|HEAD  | users                   | users.index   | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@index                       | web        |
|        | POST      | users                   | users.store   | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@store                       | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | users/create            | users.create  | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@create                      | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | users/{users}           | users.show    | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@show                        | web        |
|        | PUT|PATCH | users/{users}           | users.update  | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@update                      | web        |
|        | DELETE    | users/{users}           | users.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@destroy                     | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | users/{users}/edit      | users.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@edit                        | web        |
```

If you then create another route `Route::get('users', 'UserController@getUsers');` it will conflict with the first route defined by your `resource` route.

So you need to make sure you don't have conflicting routes.